# Helm Hook for checking correct release or release is already available

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to create a helm hook to check whether the chart release already exists before install or upgrade. If not exists, it starts a fresh install. (Check for the revision would also be nice).

I am having trouble with writing the spec for above functions.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
 name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
 labels:
   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
   app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
   app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
   helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
 annotations:
   # hooks are defined here
   "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade,pre-install
   #"helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
   "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded,before-hook-creation
spec:
 template:
   metadata:
     name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
     labels:
       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
       app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
       helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
   spec:
```

Comment: That seems like it's fundamentally the difference between "install" (a new not-already-installed release) and "upgrade" (an existing release).  Are you looking for anything more than this, maybe via [`.Release.IsUpgrade`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/)?  What would you do differently in the two cases?

Comment: In that case, i would like to create two test cases (two hooks) for pre-install and pre-upgrade. For pre-install, I would like to check whether the Chat .Release.Name has not been deployed and not already exists(ensure fresh chart installation). 
And for the pre-upgrade, I would like to check Release.IsUpgrade is true.
I am having trouble understanding the syntax of writing further spec with this idea.

Comment: If a pre-install hook runs (at all) then the release isn't installed yet.  If a pre-upgrade hook runs then it is.  You don't need to separately check this.